# PHP find all class name including extends classes if exists

Tags: php, class

I am trying to find list of all class including extended class too. I have tried `get_declared_classes()` but it is excluding all extended classes.

Any way to get all classes including extends?

```
class profile extends Authentication
{
// methods
}
```

So I want to find `Authentication` as well as `profile`

Comment: What do you refer to by "extended classes"? Derived classes? Those should be listed...

Comment: @arkascha I have updated question with example. I want to list all class name as well as `extends` class name too

Comment: Those are indeed derived classes. I just made a short test script and I can confirm: derived classes _are_ listed.

Comment: I have checked and found it is ignoring few of them. FYI, I am using Codeigniter

Comment: That function just lists the global namespace filtered towards classes. If it does not list a class it is not defined. The function does not randomly ignore a few or something. Note: this would just mean that the classes _currently_ do not exist. Maybe it is an issue with including stuff?

Comment: You mean `extends` class will be only listed if it is in use or loaded on the current page? I have cross checked and it is listing the `extends` class if I am on that page.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/47296/discussion-between-arkascha-and-jatin-soni)